# Aligning Social Media Buttons

Tags: html, css, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to align our 3 social media buttons : Facebook/Twitter/Google +, evenly in a 393px width gap. They are aligned horizontally (facebook seems to be down about 2 px vertically on twitter/google+), however I am struggling a little and hoping someone can help.

Below is the code of the CSS/HTML buttons:

HTML

```
 <div class="nav-container2">
    <div id="nav3"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Foscam-UK/222224154548563" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="20" data-show-faces="false"></div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/FoscamUK" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @FoscamUK</a>  
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-container2 { width:940px; margin:auto; height:30px;}
#nav2 { width:547px; height:40px; float:right; margin:1px 0 0 0; font-size:105%; background:url(../images/bg-nav.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc; }
#nav3 { width:393px; float:left; height:0px; margin-top:10px;}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="nav-container2">
    <ul class="social-media-list">
        <li>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Foscam-UK/222224154548563" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="20" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/FoscamUK" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @FoscamUK</a> 
        </li>
        <li> 
            <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-container2 { width:940px; margin:auto; height:30px;}
.social-media-list { width: 393px; }
.social-media-list li { display:block; float: left; width:33.3%; text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;}
```

This is just a guess because I'm not sure how this will fit in your page but that will give you a 393px wide block element with 3 evenly spaced list items.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="nav-container2">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Foscam-UK/222224154548563" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="20" data-show-faces="false">x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/FoscamUK" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @FoscamUK</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium">y</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-container2 { width:940px; margin:auto; height:30px; background-color: #ace}
.nav-container2 ul div {display: inline;}
.nav-container2 li {display: inline; border: 1px solid #000; width: 33%; float: left;}
```

Based on previous answer. `borders` and `background-color` were added to show what was going on.